# where to get oracle database vm without oracle account?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to install Oracle database either 11g or 12c but since I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and since I neither have oracle account nor able to have one I was looking for virtual box image that contain the database.
note : I was thinking to create windows VM and then install Oracle database inside it but I can not find 32 bit version of the database for that purpose.
Please take into consideration I neither have oracle account nor able to have one and I need the database just for educational purposes.

Comment: Why aren't you able to get an Oracle account?  They're free.  You can sign up online in very little time.  The only reason I can think of is that you're in an embargoed country.  If that's the case, you probably want to be clear about that obstacle in your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because user appears to be asking how to get software illicitly

Comment: User's profile says that he is in Syria, and the Oracle TOS says the software and website may not be used there.

Answer (score 1):

Download Oracle Virtual Box from here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html

Download Oracle Linux from here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/linux/downloads/index.html

Download Oracle database from here:  https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html

The license agreement for database downloads from OTN specifically states that it is free to use for personal learning.

Comment: the last step you suggested https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html require oracle account

Comment: It's just an OTN account.  It's free.  Why can't you create one?